# What is the use case of an expression inside a class without storing it in a value/variable?

Tags: scala, expression

Example here with scala:

I have a class and inside an expression,

```
class A{
  if (1==3) 45 else 90
}
```

When is this type of expression used inside a class.
(is it for like Flow, Streams , ...)

Answer (score 5):

An expression that doesn't get assigned to a val or var is only ever useful if the expression is side effecting, eg if it does some IO or invokes a method that updates a var somewhere else etc. In your case, above, since the expression is not side effecting, it is useless, and I wouldn't be surprised if it was optimised out of existence by the time it runs.

The expression by the way, assuming it wasn't optimised away, would be run as part of class `A`'s constructor.

Comment: Sadly, no `a pure expression does nothing in statement position` message. Refchecks does `Eliminate branches in a conditional if the condition is a constant`.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement James' answer let's analyse if it was

> optimised out of existence by the time it runs

Executing `scalac -print` gives something like

```
def <init>(...) = {
  A.super.<init>();
  90;
  ()
}
```

So the expression was reduced to just `90`, and examining bytecode output of `javap -c`

```
12: invokespecial #21                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
15: bipush        90
17: pop
18: return
```

we see there exists `bipush 90`. However, compiling with `-optimise` flag and examining emitted bytecode

```
12: invokespecial #21                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
15: return
```

it seems `bipush 90` is completely gone.